# functional test for Rails plugin, assert_template broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm writing a plugin that adds a class method to `ActionController::Base`, so in my functional test I am creating a simple controller to test against. The example below is totally stripped down to basically do nothing. The test succeeds all the way up to `assert_template`, which fails.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/test_case'
require 'action_controller'
require 'action_controller/test_process'

class UnderTestController < ActionController::Base
  def index; end
end
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw {|map| map.resources :under_test }

class MyPluginTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @controller = UnderTestController.new
    @request    = ActionController::TestRequest.new
    @response   = ActionController::TestResponse.new
  end

  test "should render the correct template" do
    get :index
    assert_template :index  # everything works except this assert
  end
end
```

Here are the results from running the above file:

```
Loaded suite /Users/jjulian/sandbox/vendor/plugins/my_plugin/test/my_plugin_test
Started
E 
Finished in 0.014567 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_should_render_the_correct_template(MyPluginTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
method assert_template in response_assertions.rb at line 103
method clean_backtrace in test_case.rb at line 114
method assert_template in response_assertions.rb at line 100
method test_should_render_the_correct_template in so_test.rb at line 22
method __send__ in setup_and_teardown.rb at line 62
method run in setup_and_teardown.rb at line 62

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

My questions: what am I missing to allow `assert_template` to work? Am I requiring the correct libraries? Extending the correct TestCase class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. First, the missing template is because the `view_path` needs to be explicitly set in the controller under test:

```
before_filter {|c| c.prepend_view_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fixtures')) }
```

I created a dummy erb file in `test/fixtures/under_test/index.erb`. That brings me back to the nil error in `response_assertions.rb`. Well, it looks like I need to include another test class:

```
require 'action_view/test_case'
```

Now it works.

One additional note: `assert_template` uses `match` to determine success, so in this case, `assert_template 'ind'` would succeed, as would `assert_template 'x'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the setup method in the test with just `tests UnderTestController`.  Rails takes care of setting up the test controller, request and response for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. That moves me forward to a more concrete error: `Missing template under_test/index.erb in view path` This makes sense. How should I stub the view template?

Comment: I think "missing template" is to be expected as a result of get :index.  Not sure though.